# How to export entire FBA users database to Excel?

Tags: user-profile, export

I have migrated from WSS 3.0 to SharePoint 2010 and we use FBA.

I need to export the entire user database to Excel.

I need to know how to do it?

Comment: which database ? the standard asp.net sql profiles database ?

Comment: yes asp.net sql profiles

Comment: so it actually a asp.net related question. Muhimbi's answer should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look in your web.config you'll see which FBA SQL database is being used. This is a standard SQL Database that you can Query from using any SQL tool, [Including Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010217956.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to extract a particular group of users from entire user database using your option?

Comment: Probably, it is just a SQL Server database, just query away. In depth details can be found at http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb